# I'm unable to add google fonts and a weather widget to a Github page

Tags: html, css, github, fonts, github-pages

I'm a newbie to web developing and I've just put a very simple page up on github pages, [here](https://mrfundira.github.io/). It's a simple site that I had to make for a class. I didn't even have to build one (could have used wix, etc) but decided to challenge myself. Not the greatest design, but adequate for my needs. I have two main issues however: none of the Google Fonts that I've included load, despite working fine when I open the html from my hard disk. Here's an html snippet:

```
<!-- Google fonts, Lato, Arvo, Josefin Slab (semi-bold), Open Sans -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet'     type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The rest of my style works fine, so I don't think it's related to my custom stylesheets.
Secondly, my professor also asked me to include a widget (don't ask me why) that auto updates. I've got a weather widget that should show up at the bottom in a div, and does when I open the version of this page i have on my hard disk, but not on the github page. Code snippet for the div:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/purchase-ny/10577/weather-forecast/2171128"     class="aw-widget-legal">
<!--
By accessing and/or using this code snippet, you agree to AccuWeather’s terms and     conditions (in English) which can be found at http://www.accuweather.com/en/free-weather-widgets/terms and AccuWeather’s Privacy Statement (in English) which can be found at http://www.accuweather.com/en/privacy.
-->
</a><div id="awcc1398306407704" class="aw-widget-current"  data-locationkey="" data-unit="f" data-language="en-us" data-useip="true" data-uid="awcc1398306407704"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>
      </div>
```

Here's the [link to the repo](https://github.com/MrFundira/MrFundira.github.io). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That is a lot of fonts.

Comment: Well, you have the link in the head, and you have the font declarations in your css...

Comment: I think you are doing yourself a disservice by using bootstrap at this point. This site could be made with like, 100 lines of code - and you would learn a lot more. Just an opinion. Good luck!

Comment: @sheriffderek Thanks for the input! You're right, it's a really simple website and I teach myself to do it from the ground up, just had relatively tight deadlines with this. I don't intend to use bootstrap as a crutch in the future. Do you think I went a bit overboard with the fonts? I figured out the problem too, the font links were http while the page itself is https. That's fixed now but I still need to figure out how to use the widget.

Comment: I'm not a type specialist - but generally, people use 1 body font, (with a few bold, italic etc) and 1 heading font... maybe 1 more auxiliary font for special stuff. Your widget isn't working because jQuery isn't being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[blocked] The page at 'https://mrfundira.github.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

This is the error in the console (dev tools) command>option>i

A few other things aren't loading properly either / looks like jQuery - which could be your widget issue.

Comment: You fonts are working now. get that jQuery loading - and a `margin:0; padding: 0` on that ul - and you'll be in action